# probability of not occurring either A or B

Tags: probability

> In an event, $P(A)=0.6$, $P(B)=0.2$, $P(A ∩ B)=0.1$. what is the
>   probability of not occurring either A or B.

I am facing problem with the language. I don't understand what "not occurring either A or B" means. I assumed it is "not occurring event A or event B", and solved as follows-

P(not A or not B) = $1-  P(AUB)$ = $1-(0.6+0.2-0.1)$ = 0.3

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. This method generalises to any number of events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am facing problem with the language. I don't understand what "not occurring either A or B" means

Yes, it is awkward wording, but does seem to intend to say "neither A nor B occurring."

Which is $(A\cup B)^\complement$, making you calculations correct.